# Using events from a second mouse in my application independently from the primary mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I would like to use a second mouse in my C# WPF application independently from my primary mouse.

So the primary mouse controls the cursor and the mouse buttons triggers the usual click, drag, mouse wheel, etc. events

From the second mouse I would like to receive the mouse move and click events but this one should not move the mouse cursor and should not be handled by the application itself e.g. fire a button command.

In the end I will send the mouse move X/Y delta and mouse click to another device to handle them.

So something like this

```
private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var delta = oldPosition - e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(this);

        DoSomething(delta);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I found some links to Microsoft Multipoint SDK but this seems to be inactive since 2013 and I couldn't find any good examples.

On the other hand I found some applications using [Raw Input](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard) to identify the keyboard / mouse device but I couldn't figure out how to listen to the events from the second mouse without influencing the mouse cursor and application.

Does anybody has a good idea or staring point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I tried a lot of different solution but I didn't get happy with one of them.

In the end I found this nice solution

[Interception](http://www.oblita.com/interception.html)

that fits my needs. You need to install a software component and this one seems to hack in the system somewhere in between the mouse + keyboard and the OS kernel. From now on you can listen to the mouse/keyboard events from your software and modify them.